# python file-handling formatting

Tags: python, dictionary, file-handling

Please help, I have a dictionary which I need to write to a txt file I need to change the formatting of the dic so that when I write to new file I can get the desired output below. Thanks!

my dict:

```
sdata = {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': [128, 118], 'C': [5, 6, 7], 'D': [1, 3, 4]}
```

current output:

```
{'A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': [128, 118], 'C': [5, 6, 7], 'D': [1, 3, 4]}
```

how can I save it to file in the format below instead of the one above?

Desired output:

```
 A, 1 2 3 4
 
 B, 128 118
 
 C, 5 6 7
 
 D, 1 3 4
```

following is my code:

```
def saveAndExit(sdata, x, r):
    outFileName = "updated.txt"
    outfile = open(outFileName, "w")
    print (f'Content of xxx after updated {x} was added to key{r}:')
    print (f'Content of xxx after updated {x} was added to key{r}:',file=outfile)
    print (sdata) # wrong format
    print (sdata, file=outfile)
    outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do what you want:

```
for key, value in sdata.items():
    print(key + ", " + " ".join(str(v) for v in value))
```

This produces the following:

```
A, 1 2 3 4
B, 128 118
C, 5 6 7
D, 1 3 4
```

If you want to double-space the output, with blank lines between each line of data (as shown in the post), just add:

```
print()
```

to the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would use unpacking operator (`*`) in `print` to get desired result, following way:

```
sdata = {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': [128, 118], 'C': [5, 6, 7], 'D': [1, 3, 4]}
for key, value in sdata.items():
    print(f'{key},', *value, end='\n\n')
```

Output:

```
A, 1 2 3 4

B, 128 118

C, 5 6 7

D, 1 3 4
```

providing '\n\n' as end result to get blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print('\n\n'.join("%s, %s" % (k,str(sdata[k]).strip("[]").replace(",","")) for k in sdata.keys()))
```

The above will ensure the keys are stripped off brackets and commas. You can omit those if you want to.

Output:

```
A, 1 2 3 4

B, 128 118

C, 5 6 7

D, 1 3 4
```